# unix - how to create a single string from a list of multiple outputs

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I've got a snippet here that i'm running on the command line which creates the following output:

```
$ { time mysql -u root -N -e "select NOW();" >/dev/null; } 2>&1 | grep real; echo ":localhost:"; date +"%m-%d-%y"
real    0m0.022s
:localhost:
04-28-17
```

I'd like my output to be a single string like so: (or delimited by whatever I choose as delimiter if possible)

```
real    0m0.022s :localhost:04-28-17
```

What command can I use to concat or join to create my string? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work, assuming `bash` as your shell:

```
echo "$(grep real < <({ time mysql -u root -N -e 'select NOW();'; } 2>&1)):localhost:$(date +'%m-%d-%y')"
```

The first `$(...)` could also be your original `{ time mysql -u root -N -e 'select NOW();'; } 2>&1 | grep real`. I don't see a particularly compelling reason to prefer one way over the other.

The core concept, though, is that doing `echo "$(...)"` strips trailing newlines off the output of whatever's inside `$(...)`...

Comment: This works for me. Thanks @twalberg and for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap that whole beast up and send it to `sed` to wipe out the linefeeds:

```
 { { time mysql -u root -N -e "select NOW();" >/dev/null; } 2>&1 | grep real; echo ":localhost:"; date +"%m-%d-%y"; } | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'
```

In Action:

```
$ { { time mysql -u root -N -e "select NOW();" >/dev/null; } 2>&1 | grep real; echo ":localhost:"; date +"%m-%d-%y"; } | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'
real    0m0.412s :localhost: 04-28-17
```

Comment: Strange bananas. Worked fine for me.